# Error while setting up Firebase notification on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use the Firebase for Notifications and I integrated it exactly as described in the docs.

I tried to send a sample message to the app, but it doesn't work. I looked closer in the logs and I saw the following error message.

```
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid
```

Could that be related to my problems?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was, that the certificates for push notifications where not valid in the developer console of Firebase. Renewing them fixed the problem.